# Ternary operator in string template

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is a compact way to build a string with optional parameters like this?

```
let q = `CREATE "a"
            ${this.date ? ` SET date = '${this.date}'` : ''}
            ${this.description ? ` SET description = '${this.description}'` : ''}
            RETURN n`;
```

without that `else` case returning  an empty string `''`?

**Edit:** The current results is:

```
CREATE "a"


RETURN n
```

This is just an aesthetic issue, I would prefer not having those empty lines

---

Using boolean operator `&&` doesn't work (it returns `undefined` as string):

```
${this.date && ` SET date = '${this.date}'`}
```

Comment: If you don’t want an empty string, what else do you expect there?

Comment: You can always use a helper function that does what you want

Comment: If it was me I would create conditional substrings separately just for readability

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to build SQL strings like that anyway, without proper escaping. Use prepared statements or your [sql driver's equivalent](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)!

Comment: it is not an SQL query, it's a Cypher query (NEO4j). I edited the question with more details

Comment: To avoid the aesthetic issue, you need to put the linebreak inside the string in the THEN part of the conditional, not after the interpolation expression.

Comment: @alfredopacino You would still need escaping, whatever query language it is. Why not use something like [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypher-query)?

Comment: @Bergi thanks I will try that package, but it's a bit too late in my project :), I use the official nodejs driver (very basic, without an official Object mapper).  Honestly I'm not so clear with your previous answer, I do not use any explicit linebreak, could you post an answer?

Comment: @alfredopacino Not an object mapper, but surely it has the capability to escape values in queries? (I couldn't find the relevant docs with a cursory search)

Comment: @Bergi Also, I'm not clear what do you mean with escaping values. Do you mean it for security reason? In this case it's not a real production project. Beside that, that package really looks like relies on an old cypher version.

Comment: @alfredopacino Escaping for correctness and security, yes. It doesn't matter that it's not for production, one just doesn't do this wrong.

Comment: @alfredopacino The common issue with a query like this is that `this.date`, if it ever comes from an untrusted source, could contain something that looks like a query, which would break this code. Line `date === "' SET description='some other value`, which would set the date to an empty string, and also set a description, even though only `this.date` was set.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **condition && value || ""**, but that's almost equivalent to using ternary operator.

Another available option is to try **tagged template** here that discards empty values:

```js
    let date;
    let description = "description";

    function nonEmpty(parts) {
        var res = parts[0];
        for (var i=1; i<parts.length; i++) {
            if (arguments[i]) // you might want to handle `0` different
                res += arguments[i];
            res += parts[i];
        }
        return res;
    }

    console.log(nonEmpty`Date :: ${date} and Description :: ${description}`);
```

Comment: Almost equivalent but much worse, yes.

Comment: The template tag is a good suggestion, though you wouldn't need to use `&&` at all there.

Comment: good point @bergi with template tag we don't need to add && ,  corrected the answer accordingly, thanks